# Weird behavior with Python os.system and mysqldump

Tags: python, mysql

When I try and do a mysqldump on a remote host using the command line it will work perfectly

```
mysqldump -alv -h some_ip_here -Psome_port -usome_user some_db_name > /tmp/dumps/some_dump_file.sql
```

However, when I try the same thing in Python using `os.command`, I get a weird access denied error.

```
import os

command = 'mysqldump -alv -h some_host_ip -Psome_port -usome_user some_db_name > /tmp/dumps/some_dump_file.sql'

os.system(command)
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Error message of the Python implementation below

```
-- Connecting to some_host_ip...
mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'some_user'@'some_other_host_ip' (using password: YES) when trying to connect
```

Comment: have you used password?

Comment: Yea you can ignore all the password stuff - behavior is the same

Comment: When you execute the command from the command line, `some_dump_file` is the local folder. When you do it from inside Python, the implied location of the file is almost certainly somewhere else. Try the call to `os.system()` with a completely explicit path and filename. And, once you get it working, switch to using module `subprocess` instead of `os.system()`.

Comment: @BoarGules I had been using the following path: /tmp/dumps/some_dump_file.sql